# Rails - How to override method in Module which is inside Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, overriding

I want to **override** `marshal` method in `ActiveRecord` but not sure how to do for a method inside module inside a Class

```
module ActiveRecord
 class SessionStore < ActionDispatch::Session::AbstractStore
   module ClassMethods
      def marshal(data)
        ::Base64.encode64(Marshal.dump(data)) if data
      end
   end
 end
end
```

I've tried this on `config/initializers/active_record.rb`

```
ActiveRecord::SessionStore.class_eval do
 ClassMethods.module_eval do
   def marshal(data)
      # Code
   end
 end
end
```

But it throws an error

```
config/initializers/active_record.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant ClassMethods (NameError)
```

**EDIT**

I am trying to override from `config/initializers/active_record.rb`, dont wanna edit gem file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this simpler using:

```
ActiveRecord::SessionStore::ClassMethods.module_eval do
  def marshal(data)
    // code
  end
end
```

or even simpler

```
module ActiveRecord::SessionStore::ClassMethods
  def marshal(data)
    // code
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried simply redefining?

```
module ActiveRecord
  class SessionStore
    module ClassMethods
      def marshal(data)
        # Code
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: LOL, it's effectively the same.

Comment: Edited the question. FYI If I edit gem file it would be hard to push changes in Git